# build a numpy array without using for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have two numpy array of shape `(N, 3)` like

```
array1 = np.array([[x1, y1, 1],
                   ........
                   [xn, yn, 1]])

array2 = np.array([[u1, v1, 1],
                   ........
                   [un, vn, 1]])
```

I want

```
A = np.array([[x1 * u1, x1 * v1, x1, y1 * u1, y1 * v1, y1, u1, v1, 1],
              .........
              [xn * un, xn * vn, xn, yn * un, yn * vn, yn, un, vn, 1]]
```

How should I do it without using `for` loops to iterate through?

Comment: I thought that there was only one possible interpretation for your output, but you have two answers that conform to what you've shown here. Could you clarify if you want to broadcast or permute the first dimension?

Answer (score 1):

This is called Kronecker product. You can do that using `np.kron()` function like:

```py
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([[1,2,1], 
                   [3,4,1]])
array2 = np.array([[3,4,1], 
                   [1,0,1]])
N = array1.shape[0]
result = np.kron(array1, array2)

# A (NxN) x 9 output
#array([[ 3,  4,  1,  6,  8,  2,  3,  4,  1],
#       [ 1,  0,  1,  2,  0,  2,  1,  0,  1],
#       [ 9, 12,  3, 12, 16,  4,  3,  4,  1],
#       [ 3,  0,  3,  4,  0,  4,  1,  0,  1]])
```

If you want a one to one Kronecker product, you might also use:

```py
# N x 9 
np.kron(array1, array2)[0:N*N:N, :]
#array([[ 3,  4,  1,  6,  8,  2,  3,  4,  1],
#       [ 9, 12,  3, 12, 16,  4,  3,  4,  1]])
```

which is not recommended if performance matters.

Comment: OP only wants along one axis. Very close though.

Comment: @MadPhysicist That could be and could not be true, cause the OP doesn't mention the output's dimension.

Comment: OP's out is quite clear I think, but I suppose that your interpretation is not explicitly forbidden.

Comment: Either way, +1 for mentioning `kron`. It's useful and at the very least, quite relevant.

Comment: I am confused since I get different result using np.kron and the method below, which one is false?

Comment: @chaomeng What is the dimension of your expected output?

Comment: I think it should be Nx9, kron gives a 2Nx9

Comment: @chaomeng In that case you can use `np.kron(array1, array2)[0:N*N:N, :]` or use the other answer which gives you what you want

Answer (score 1):

You clearly want a broadcasted multiplication along the second dimension. The trick with all problems like these is to remember that numpy ravels/reshapes in C order by default.

Let's analyze the rows of the output to see how to arrange the product. You have

```
[x1 * u1, x1 * v1, x1 * 1, y1 * u1, y1 * v1, y1 * 1, u1, v1, 1]
```

This is the raveled version of

```
[[x1 * u1, x1 * v1, x1 * 1],
 [y1 * u1, y1 * v1, y1 * 1],
 [ 1 * u1,  1 * v1,  1 * 1]]
```

Which in turn is the product

```
array1[0][:, None] * array2[0][None, :]
```

So the product you want keeps the first dimension and broadcasts the second as shown above. Then you ravel the last two dimensions together to get the partial Kronecker product:

```
A = (array1[:, :, None] * array2[:, None, :]).reshape(array1.shape[0], -1)
```